# "Already being wealthy" or "being already wealthy"

Tags: grammar

In spite of **already** being  wealthy, he is very greedy.

In spite of being **already**  wealthy, he is very greedy.

Where should "**already**" be placed?

Comment: I think the sentence you need is: "In spire of being wealthy, he is still very greedy".

Answer (score 1):

Both are fine. I quite prefer the first one (strictly my personal opinion), but the second is not wrong either. I'm not aware of any significant difference in the meaning between the two.

Here are references for the use of both syntaxes:

> There are even those who feel fortunate at **being already wealthy** -
>   though not super-rich yet.

<sup>[Modern Rules of Personal Finance for Professionals](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=Aa2Nte7uwYIC&pg=PR7&lpg=PR7&dq=%22being%20already%20wealthy%22&source=bl&ots=Ev9ioENEn6&sig=c-qwb2au3yBAmtigYJHSGHaHv0s&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjKicKu1JvPAhXLMj4KHdeiBwgQ6AEILDAD#v=onepage&q=%22being%20already%20wealthy%22&f=false) by Susan A. Berson, Introduction, page vii.</sup>

> But there's a difference between **already being wealthy** and being
>   rewarded for failure.

<sup>[The Oxford Handbook of Austrian Economics](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=EnU_CgAAQBAJ&pg=PA758&lpg=PA758&dq=%22already%20being%20wealthy%22&source=bl&ots=CZ_OCLltyJ&sig=SFFvkDg3hJGIUuANwLTl2k4z9qo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjpnau01ZvPAhWEaT4KHe6HCXYQ6AEIJjAC#v=onepage&q=%22already%20being%20wealthy%22&f=false) edited by Peter J. Boettke, Christopher J. Coyne, page 758</sup>

"Already being wealthy" has [43 hits (in quotes), on Google](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=%22being%20already%20wealthy%22&oq=%22being%20already%20wealthy%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j69i61&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), "being already wealthy" [has 33](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=%22being%20already%20wealthy%22&oq=%22being%20already%20wealthy%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j69i61&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). This is a relatively minor difference and you may use whichever one you prefer. But personally, I would go for "**already being wealthy**". The only hard evidence I have for this recommendation is the slightly higher number of hits on Google, which indicates that it may be *slightly* more used. However, the sample is small. Honestly, I'm basing it on what I personally think *sounds* better.